# in C# how to generate JSON body, having key as string and token as string and key as string and token as List

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I need to generate following JSON, I have tried to use JavaScriptSerializer but I am unable to find the solution, need guidance to achieve the same.

```
{
    "task": {
        "taskState": "Running",
        "taskStatus": "Ok",
        "completedSteps": 1,
        "taskProgress": [{
            "message": "test message",
            "timeStamp": "date_time"
        }]
    }
}
```

I know its pretty basic, but I am stuck at this point from quite some time now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Dictionary so you can easily add any kind of objects to value of your dictionary like below;

```
Dictionary<string,object> myDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
myDict.Add("StringList", new List<string>() { "string1", "string2" });
myDict.Add("Bool", false);
myDict.Add("Int", 2016);
```

---

**Improved answer: Matches given sample Json**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO_39849909
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> myDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            myDict.Add("task", new Dictionary<string, object>());

            Dictionary<string, object> innerDict = (myDict["task"] as Dictionary<string, object>);
            innerDict.Add("taskState", "Running");
            innerDict.Add("taskStatus", "Ok");
            innerDict.Add("completedSteps", 1);
            innerDict.Add("taskProgress", new List<dynamic>());

            List<dynamic> taskProgress = (innerDict["taskProgress"] as List<dynamic>);
            taskProgress.Add(new { message = "test message", timeStamp = DateTime.Now });

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Also working example from dotnetfiddle is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYcZKp

Then you can serialize that dictionary to json.

*PS: As a advice you may consider using Newtonsoft.Json (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)*

*PS-Edit: Consider using dynamic expression which may have heavy cost on runtime resolving.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to implement the solution for my case, as in case of: `"taskProgress": [{
            "message": "test message",
            "timeStamp": "date_time"
        }]`, my test message and date_time is dynamic, also it would be helpful if u can address the solution in context of my solution. Thanks

Comment: So I have modified my answer and also created a working example which meets 1:1 with your sample JSON @Sumit hope this was what u expect.

Comment: Thanks Cihan for detailed response, this will be an alternative solution to my problem, as previously I was using JObject to construct my jSON response, coz of which even though I was able to create the "taskProgress" list when I was passing it in JObject via add the respective parameter as jToken, it was always going as string, which was creating issues. But your solution is working for me, so thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string data_call()
    {
        string result="";
        Data td=new Data();
        List<spselect_data_Result> selectdata=td.spselect_data().ToList();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("RegValues",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("StartDate",typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("EndDate",typeof(DateTime));

        foreach(var add in selectdata)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(add.RegValues,add.StartDate,add.EndDate);
        }
        result=DataSetToJSON(dt);
        return result;
    }

      public static string DataSetToJSON(DataTable dt)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }

       // dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
        dict.Add("response", arr);
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(dict);

    }
```

this `DataSetToJSON` generate result in JSON format